# Are app specific questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Are questions like the following appropriate?

"I'm using application X, can you tell me how to do Y with app X?"

Comment: What if App X isn't android-specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they're appropriate.  In fact, I think they're far more relevant to the mission of the site than the mass of `What's the best [X] app?` questions.

These are real questions with objective answers that are specific to the Android platform, so yes, please ask them.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes. Certainly for built-in and Google applications. For more obscure application maybe not, but those are less likely to get answers anyways